# How to communicate with a specific ECU using its physical address

Tags: obd-ii

Each time I send a query to the OBD2 I get two responses. 
For instance, if I send 0105, I get

`41 05 5C
 7F 01 12`

If I turn on header with AT H1 and then send 0105, I get

`83 F1 11 41 05 5C
 83 F1 18 7F 01 12`

I only need the first response, the one from `83 F1 11` 
please, how do I specify that I want to communicate with only that ECU?

From "ELM Electronics - Circuits for the Hobbyist" 
I know it should be done using AT SH but there are three options
available and I do not know which one to use:

AT SH xyz or AT SH xxyyzz or AT SH wwxxyyzz.

Btw my car is a Hyundai Tucson 2006, and runs protocol 5 that is
ISO 14230-4 KWP (fast init, 10.4 kbaud)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways. The most complicated one is setting the header address directly via `ATSH`. Way easier is appending the number of expected responses to the pid, i.e. `01001` will send `0100` and discards all but one response. The fastest ECU will win, which is not always what you want.

So another way is to filter by header, i.e.:

```
>0100
18 DA F1 10 06 41 00 B8 7B 30 10 00
18 DA F1 17 06 41 00 80 00 80 03 00

>AT CRA 18DAF117
OK

>0100
18 DA F1 17 06 41 00 80 00 80 03 00
```

Comment: This works for CAN but how do you filter for ISO14230? the header  in the poster is         83 F1 11 41 05 5C  which means (80 +3) 3 bytes|F1=reader|11=target|<data> say I only want to see replies from 11, can be done in a loop but is there a way to do it on the ELM???

Comment: I have a similar problem. The ELM327 is quite simple and is lacking basic functionality. I recommend to use J2534 adapter instead (e.g. Tactrix OpenPort) which is far more flexible.

Comment: I wonder about that myself. It looks like you need to do application-level filtering then. See also my (unanswered) question over here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/88437/j1850-vpwm-physical-addressing-3-byte-header